# Ansible - Add a word to a specific line in a specific part of that line

Tags: ansible

I want to add the word "nodev" to the line that contain /home in /etc/fstab file
here's the file before

```
UUID=2ea6e2e5-d902-4289-b516-40c175cd481b /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
UUID=114107f7-5b48-44b7-ad38-09b47b1d6b02 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=830757d1-60ad-4f4a-b41a-cad04d309e9d /home                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=4b309559-2391-4f28-b2f5-38029e278db0 /tmp                    ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=1dfc4cab-4de4-491f-8bd0-3503e9027717 /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=f0846773-528b-42a2-a0dc-7a736595f7e1 /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=25ef70f1-7083-4a9b-a64c-970f5d4ad742 /var/log/audit          xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=40d2f177-aa5c-43a1-9d85-e21bf2bafb39 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

Here's what i want to have

```
UUID=2ea6e2e5-d902-4289-b516-40c175cd481b /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
UUID=114107f7-5b48-44b7-ad38-09b47b1d6b02 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=830757d1-60ad-4f4a-b41a-cad04d309e9d /home                   ext3    defaults,nodev        1 2
UUID=4b309559-2391-4f28-b2f5-38029e278db0 /tmp                    ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=1dfc4cab-4de4-491f-8bd0-3503e9027717 /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=f0846773-528b-42a2-a0dc-7a736595f7e1 /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=25ef70f1-7083-4a9b-a64c-970f5d4ad742 /var/log/audit          xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=40d2f177-aa5c-43a1-9d85-e21bf2bafb39 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

How can i do that using ansible and lineinfile module?

Comment: Why must you use `lineinfile` ?

Comment: I have chosen lineinfile because it was the recommended for editing file by ansible. if there is other solution am open but always using ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `lineinfile`, maybe, assuming the format of the file does not change, and `defaults` is there to constrain the match, after which the `nodev` option and the rest of the line can be added:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/fstab
        regexp: '^(\S+\s+/home\s+\S+\s+defaults)'
        line: '\1,nodev 1 2'
        backrefs: yes
```

as tested with:

```
$ ansible-playbook lineinfile.yml
$ diff /tmp/fstab.orig /tmp/fstab
```

though for mount points there is the [mount module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html#mount-module) that may be less fragile than regex parsing of `fstab`. On the other hand the regex will not care what the UUID is, while a `mount` module entry may need something specific there that could vary across hosts. An additional rule or script that tests that the appropriate filesystem device is set may be necessary to catch the low but not zero odds that the regex fails.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.